# How to deal with FutureWarning: Int64Index.flags is deprecated and will be removed in a future version?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm doing a Grid Search passing custom cross validation folds with a list with indices and getting this warning, Why I'm getting this warnings message?  and how to avoid this warning?

> My indexes are type 'int64'.

Note: I don't want to simply suppress the warning. I need a solution so that without adding `suppress warning`, current warnings should vanish.

Comment: `import warnings warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')` What about this?

Comment: I actually would like to get to the solution that will keep working on next version.

Comment: I dont care about how to disable warnings, my question is what is a solution that won't have any warning but not thanks to disabling the warnings but thanks to modifying something in the code if that solution exists

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?